# How to center items within css grid columns?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

pen view: https://codepen.io/peter952001/pen/wvqrKwR

I am a beginner in CSS and trying to build a blog website (using Django) from scratch. I wanted to make cards responsible for each blog post on the home page like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-wrapper">
        <div class="card">
        <!-- Some post info -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I am not able to make the cards centred according to their number (max is 5 per row). So, as in the pen view, I want the three cards to be centred, and if another post is added, the four get centred accordingly. Here is the css:

```
.card-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(240px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.card {
    height: 520px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
    background: #fff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

I think the problem is in the `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(240px, 1fr));` line but I don't know how to fix it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The problem is in the grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(240px, 1fr)); line.
you can change it from absolute value to relative value. like that:

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(30%, 1fr));`

```
.container {
    min-height: 80vh;
    padding: 20px 0;
    display: flex;
}
.card-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(30%, 1fr ));
    grid-gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: This solved it. But I have one more concern: How do I keep the posts to their original width (280px)? Shall I get the ratio between its width and its container width?

Comment: @PeterFayez I updated my answear. you have to change the two class `container`and `card-wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

add to card-wrapper

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

add to container *edit

display: flex;

Comment: Mmmmm. I added it to the pen but they are still uncentered.

Comment: i see what i tried in .container i added display: flex; as well sorry i left that out!

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, Sir.